# Posting FormData to Json-Server Array using React

Tags: reactjs, json

I am trying to post formdata to an array in a json-server for a Schedule.

My db.json file on json-server is formatted as follows :

```
   {
    "schedule": {
        "monday": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Test Show",
                "time": "12:00"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Test Show 2",
                "time": "15:00"
            }
        ],
        "tuesday": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Test Show 3",
                "time": "12:00"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Test Show 4",
                "time": "15:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and my code in React is :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Card from "./card";

function Test() {
  const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://schedules.kevtucker.com",
  });

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  const noData = !data || (data && data.length === 0);

  console.log(data);
  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/schedule").catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    if (response && response.data) setData(response.data);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  const addData = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await axios.post("/schedule", formData).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    if (response) getData();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      {noData && <div>No Data</div>}
      <div>
        <h4>Monday</h4>
        {!noData &&
          data?.monday.map((data, idx) => <Card key={idx} {...data} />)}
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={addData}>
        <label>Show Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Show Name"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label>Time</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="time"
          placeholder="Time"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label>Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Id" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

My goal is when I submit the form data it will update for the given day.

When I am submitting the form it is just clearing the json file and posting the form data with :

```
{
"schedule": {
 "name": "Test Another Show",
 "time": "12:00",
 "id": "3"
}
}
```

What would be the way to solve this ?

Comment: your post url is probably incorrect.. your formData is specific to a single day while your json tracks multiple days. If you want to update monday, then you probably need to update your post to schedule because currently it points directly to the root which is the schedule but the data was specific to monday.

Comment: I have checked the post url and if i put https://schedules.kevtucker.com/schedule/monday i get an empty array.

Comment: I can see that you already updated your json-server which I think is correct. I think you won't have problems updating anymore.

Comment: Yes that way did work but thats not how i wanted to do it.

Comment: I think it's a limitation in json-server.

Comment: I think it must be.